# Php - Secure File Download Facility

Tags: php, html, https, ftp, web

I want to make a website, which only allows authentic users to download files from the browser. And any one else cannot download the file.

I have uplaoded the files with 000 access, which will restrict the users, but how to give permissions only to authentic users.?

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give a link to physical folder of a file. You may emulate it with such code(example of png):

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name.png"');
readfile($fileaddress);
```

Comment: can you give me any sample code.? what is this `header`. I am new to php. Please explain.

Comment: It is actually a bit beyond php topic. Here you can find some details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME Shortly, the code says that this is not php-file, and forces to download it with reading content from another file which physical address stays hidden from users.

Comment: here you can find good examples tht can help you: http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download